# Integrating Search module in SDL DXA 2 with Elastic Search

Tags: dxa, search, si4t, dxa-2.0

Is there any documentation or example project on integrating Search module in SDL DXA 2 with Elastic Search

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know currently SDL community available DXA integration with SOLR and AWS Cloud search modules.

@hemkant wrote blogs about ElasticSearch Integration in Web8 and ElasticSearch Module in DXA.

Blog Reference links:

[ElasticSearch Module in DXA](http://hem-kant.blogspot.nl/2017/02/elasticsearch-module-in-dxa.html)

[ElasticSearch Integration 4 WEB 8](http://hem-kant.blogspot.nl/2017/02/elasticsearch-integration-4-web-8.html)

I hope it helps.